# Use a function to calculate probabilities of non-zero values per window in rolling windows in R

Tags: r, windows, zoo, moving-average

I have a matrix with 0 and 1 as the following:

```
set.seed(9900)
M = matrix(rbinom(50, 1, 0.2), 5, 10)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
[5,]    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

And I want to have the probability that the sum of the rows contains non-zero elements. For the entire M matrix I can use the following code:

```
prob = sum(colSums(t(M) !=0) !=0)/nrow(M)
> prob
[1] 0.8
```

However, I want to use this function in rolling or sliding windows, containing 5 columns at a time and moving every one column, so that I would have one "prob" per window. I know the "zoo" package has some functions to work with rolling windows, but I do not know how to adapt it to my case. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zoo::rollapply`. I'm not entirely sure what your expected output, but here's a code that compute your functions for every two rows:

```r
library(zoo)
rollapply(t(M), width = 5, FUN = function(x) sum(colSums(x !=0) != 0) / nrow(M), by.column = F, align = "right")
# [1] 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.2 0.2
```

<sub>Note: `\` is a shortcut for `function` in lambda-like functions since R 4.1.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Maël for your answer, it is very likely what I need or close. However, when I run it I have the following error: "Error: unexpected input in "rollapply(M, 2, FUN = \". Do you have any idea what could be the error?

Comment: Yes. \ is a shortcut for `function`. Just replace \ with `function` and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes. Thanks! If I run your code using 5 instead of 2 (rollapply(M, 5, FUN = function(x) sum(rowSums(x !=0) != 0) / nrow(M), by.column = F)), I get the 0.8 again, that of course, corresponds to the whole M, that's ok. However, I want to do it by group of 5 columns, including all rows. So the first group would be column 1 to column 5, the second would be column 2 to column 6, etc.

Comment: See my edit, use width = 5 and align = "right".

Comment: Thanks for the edition in the answer. Have you tested it? I ran your code and I got just 0.8

Comment: Yes, this is because your matrix only has 5 rows. If it had 6 rows, you'd get 2 results.

Comment: It is not possible to do it in groups of 5 columns instead of 5 rows?

Comment: Also consider the equivalent `rollsumr(colSums(M != 0) != 0, 5) / nrow(M)`

Comment: The exact solution is "rollapply(t(M), width = 5, FUN = function(x) sum(colSums(x !=0) != 0) / nrow(M), by.column = F, align = "right")", which gives [1] 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.2 0.2